# How to run scheduler so that other function works in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, schedule

I thought the schedule wouldn't interfere with the bot commands but it does. After i run a schedule let's say every one minute, it blocks other functions in my bot. I'm looking for a solution to run 1 simple task via scheduler ( i'm using [this](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/) schedule module ) and keeping all the primary bot functionality - any commands or events.

Example:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == xxxxx:
        print("im working")

def test():
    print("hello")

job = schedule.every().second.do(test)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
```

I would like to run the `test` function and be able to detect messages via `on_message` function at the same time.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Are you sure it is due to the `schedule`?

Comment: Where is `func` defined?

Comment: Are you aware of [`discord.ext.tasks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html)

Comment: @12944qwerty sorry i copy pasted a different task. And no i'm not aware of it, after a quick look i supose it's a discord.py scheduler that will keep all the other functionalities working?

Comment: Exactly! Do you think you got it from here?

Comment: @12944qwerty Thank you, will look into it now! And what do you mean by "Do you think you got it from here"? Sorry, English isn't my first language i don't get it...

Comment: I was asking if you will need any more help using tasks? Please read the docs first and then come back and ask though.

Comment: @12944qwerty Ohhh, got it now... : D Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233034/discussion-between-dano-and-12944qwerty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discord.py has a feature for that, [see the full documentation here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html). Here a short example:

```
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def foo():
   print('This function runs every 5 Seconds')
```